# run threads on server side & show progress on client side possible?

Tags: multithreading, progress-bar, client-side, server-side, show

I want to run a thread pool on server side & want to show threads work progress on client side. Is this possible. If so kindly guide me. thanx in advance

Comment: Using Java 5 ThreadPool class

Comment: because I have to discovery some blades that are running and their specifications

Comment: like user want to discovery V10L balde from a specific IP range and also PCoIP Blades. The threads run on server side but I have requirement to show progress completed on client side. [Threads on server side may call a webservice, HTTP, UDP etc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the main thread check for updates (or get notified by the worker threads) and then send the report progress over TCP Sockets (or using interprocess communications if on the same  machine).

On the client side parse the information when you receive it, and update the GUI/Progress accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to open another port rather I can not open another port. I want to write it on similar stream EXAMPLE: like Gmail automatically updates your page when email received. some thing like reverse ajax call or push lets.